# How to install 32 bit Iceweasel/Firefox and Java plugin so that webex audio works on Debian 64 bit?

Tags: debian, java, 32-vs-64-bit, iceweasel, webex

Colleagues would like to communicate in a videoconference using Cisco Webex. This requires the Java plugin for Firefox/Iceweasel. Based on [this blog](https://sourcevirtues.wordpress.com/2012/07/01/enable-java-plugin-in-iceweasel-firefox-and-chrome-in-debian/), I installed the web browser plugin based on OpenJDK 7 and IcedTea:

```
apt-get install icedtea-7-plugin
```

I have access to the webex audio menu, but there is no sound. Webex uses a proprietary 32 bit sound application, according to [this page concerning Fedora](http://opensource.com/webcast/webcast-support-64-bit-linux-systems) the only fix to the sound issue seems to install a 32 bit version of Firefox / Iceweasel and of the java plugin.

I [enabled Multiarch as explained in this Debian HowTo](https://wiki.debian.org/Multiarch/HOWTO):

```
dpkg --add-architecture i386
```

I removed the 64 bit version of the java plugin (to avoid the error `trying to overwrite shared '/usr/bin/policyeditor', which is different from other instances of package icedtea-netx:i386`)

```
apt-get remove icedtea-7-plugin
```

Then I installed 32 bit version of packages:

```
apt-get install iceweasel:i386
apt-get install icedtea-7-plugin:i386
apt-get install binutils:i386 # required for flashplugin
apt-get install flashplugin-nonfree:i386
apt-get install flashplugin-nonfree-extrasound:i386
```

I tried installing a few other 32 bit packages without success.[Fedora user negativo17](http://negativo17.org/enabling-cisco-webex-in-fedora-19-x86_64-and-i686/) suggests installing Mesa’s libEG due to 2014 Mesa updates. I though It might help to install `xserver-xorg-core` for the 32 bit architecture. Somehow one of these steps broke the x-server:

```
apt-get install libegl1-mesa:i386 # suggested by Fedora user
apt-get install libepoxy0:i386 # for xorg
apt-get install xserver-xorg-core:i386 # because libegl1 reverse depends on it and I guessed the window system should also be in 32 bit for the above to work.
```

Now that iceweasel and the java plugin icedtea are installed in 32 bit. The Java webex interface starts but sound is still not working and I don't have access to the webex audio menu. Screen sharing is also not available.

[Fedora user negativo17](http://negativo17.org/enabling-cisco-webex-in-fedora-19-x86_64-and-i686/) suggests installing packages for the i386 architecture.
What architecture is recommended, should it be i386 or i686?

Comment: It sounds like you have a solution.  There is no issue with installing 32 bit applications on 64 bit Debian, and it looks like you know how to do that.  What do you need help with?

Comment: I need help with starting the 32 bit programs. the command "iceweasel" starts the 64 bit version of the program. And I might also need an alternative approach to install the non free 32 bit flash plugin as it is entering in conflict with the 64 bit version.

Comment: An alternative may be to isolate the 32-bit programs and libraries in a chroot (this is the 'old-fashioned' pre-multiarch way).  The `schroot` package may be of help with this.

Comment: Just uninstall the 64 bit programs and install the 32 bit programs.

Comment: @fixer1234 that is what I did, replacining 64 bit Iceseasel and the java plugin by the 32 bit version. Then adding more and more 32 bit libraries, until I finally broke my x server. Still without success concerning webex sound.

Comment: I have no experience with webex, but I've run into problems due to the Firefox/Iceweasel versions available in the Debian repositories being ancient, and many current addins/plugins not working.  Linux Mint Debian Edition has current versions in their repos.  Full instructions at https://support.mozilla.org/en-US/questions/1016101.  That's an easy thing to try.  If that works, you or I can write up an answer, but I don't want to post a speculative answer.

Answer (score 0):

As the comments suggest, the usual way is to replace your `iceweasel:amd64` package with the `iceweasel:i386` package and let the dependencies work through.  This is fine if all the dependent libraries are correctly multiarch compatible, but in cases where this doesn't work, a chroot install may be the best option.

To set up such a chroot the Debian way:

1. Ensure you are running a kernel that can execute IA32 ELF binaries.
2. Install `schroot` and `cdebootstrap`.
3. Create a directory of your choice (I'll use `/usr/local/roots/i386`) and run `cdebootstrap -a i386 -f minimal --include "iceweasel" testing /usr/local/roots/i386` (replace `testing` with `sid` or `jessie` or your choice of Debian release; add any other options you need).
4. Configure `schroot` to use this directory as a chroot (in `/etc/schroot/chroot.d/i386`):
   `[i386]`
   `type=directory`
   `directory=/usr/local/roots/i386`
   `profile=default`
   The `default` profile should already have bind mounts for `/home` etc - check in `/etc/schroot/default/fstab` to be sure.

Now you should be able to change into the schroot (`schroot -c i386`) and then start Iceweasel (or `sudo aptitude install` additional packages); you can start it in the chroot directory all in one command: `schroot -c i386 iceweasel`.

There's one caveat to all the above: `iceweasel` is actually a wrapper script, that looks for a running Iceweasel connected to `$DISPLAY`, and if so, uses its remote control protocol to open a new window.  So if you're running the 64-bit Iceweasel, then that will be invoked even though you thought you were starting a new 32-bit instance.  So you will need to close any native instances before starting the one in your chroot.

Comment: Thank you, I will try to install schroot over the summer and will comment  back if it works. I have replaced the webex meeting by a phone meeting for the moment.